# How sencha image url display on my carousel

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have encounter a problem, the console said my image url is not found. But it displayed well when I directly write in carousel-items-html-src,but it's not working when I use carousel.add to use data in my json.

i have found the cause:the image url is right,but when it in pass course.the image url will auto add a '/' character in the end,so  cant display. what can i do?

my controller code:

```
Ext.define('ylp2p.controller.loadpic',{
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
launch: function(){
    var storeId = Ext.create('ylp2p.store.picstore');
    var imagecarousel = Ext.getCmp('imagecarousel');
    storeId.load({
        callback: function(records,operation,success){
            Ext.each(records,function(record){
            imagecarousel.add({html: '<img src='+record.get('url')+'/>'});---is it right?
            });
        }
    });
}
});
```

the carousel in my view(part code):

```
{
                        xtype: 'carousel',
                        height: 300,
                        id: 'imagecarousel',
                        store: 'picstore'
},//end carousel
```

my json code:

```
{
"image" : [
        {"name" : "cat", "url": "http://bleachthemind.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/cute-bunnys-domestic-animals-2785589-1024-768.jpg"},
        {"name" : "lion", "url": "http://images1.fanpop.com/images/photos/2600000/Cheetah-Family-wild-animals-2603080-1280-1024.jpg"},
        {"name" : "cat", "url": "http://bleachthemind.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/cute-bunnys-domestic-animals-2785589-1024-768.jpg"}        
]
}
```

the console said:

```
"GET https://bleachthemind.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/cute-bunnys-domestic-animals-2785589-1024-768.jpg/ 404 (Not Found)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it

```
imagecarousel.add({html: '<img src='+record.get('url')+' height="100%" width="100%"/>'});
```

Comment: You should consider adding the correct quotes around the url: `'<img src="'+record.get('url')+'" />`. Use single quotes as JavaScript string concatenation quotes, and double quotes as HTML attribute value quotes. Using the quotes in correct order will make your HTML valid and help with cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: i dont why when i use this format , my chrome's carousel cant autosize the      image

Answer (score 0):

use this and check..

```
imagecarousel.add({ html: '<img src = ' + record.get('url') + '></img>' });
```

Comment: it work! but the image can't like that direct display set html's src value ,the image can't autosize?

Comment: if my answer is helpful to you as per your post and height and weight was only issue later then please check this answer as a correct answer.

Comment: no help. haha . the answer is the same as my former answer